# Phonegap IOS Signing with build.json

Tags: ios, build, phonegap-cli

I originally was using Phonegap build service to create my "debug" apps which requires a .p12 file and a provisioning file but now that they are almost ready for production I'm using a script combined with hooks to build my "release" apps locally using Phonegap cli 6.4

```
phonegap build --release --buildConfig build.json
```

I'm encountering this error in the command line

```
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: 
-xcconfig,/Users/cuesta/workspace/mobile/platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig,-workspace,myappname.xcworkspace,-scheme,myappname,-configuration,Release,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5s,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/cuesta/workspace/mobile/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/cuesta/workspace/mobile/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

After this command failed

```
CompileAssetCatalog build/emulator/myappname.app myappanem/Images.xcassets
```

My guess is that I have my build.json config wrong for IOS build. So my questions are:

-- Where do I find the "codeSignIdentity"
or please explain the following.

> Code signing identity to use for signing. It can be created with Xcode and added to your keychain. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/

-- Is development team where I put the "teamId"?

-- Is it possible that my "teamId" was generated exactly the same as my app id prefix?

I do have a prod certificate(exported to .p12) and prod provisining file ready. (Template Below)

```
"ios": {
    "debug": {
        "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Development",
        "provisioningProfile": "confirmedcorrect",
        "developmentTeam": "10or12",
        "packageType": "development"
    },
    "release": {
        "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
        "provisioningProfile": "confirmedcoorect",
        "developmentTeam": "10or12",
        "packageType": "app-store"
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed a typo in the "release" section: - "confirmedcoorect" should read "confirmedcorrect"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So many questions that I'm not sure about what to answer, so let's try answering one by one...

**Where do I find the "codeSignIdentity"?.**

Do you mean something like?

```
security find-identity -v -p codesigning
```

It will return all codesigning identities.

**Is development team where I put the "teamId"?**

Yes. If you're unsure about the ID, check https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership

**Is it possible that my "teamId" was generated exactly the same as my app id prefix?**

Yes.

Note that in the [latest (dev) revision of the documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/platforms/ios/index.html#using-buildjson) the information build.json information has changed. The new format looks like:

> ```
> {
>     "ios": {
>         "debug": {
>             "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
>             "developmentTeam": "FG35JLLMXX4A",
>             "packageType": "development",
>             "buildFlag": [
>                 "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
>                 "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
>                 "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
>             ]
>         },
>         "release": {
>             "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
>             "developmentTeam": "FG35JLLMXX4A",
>             "packageType": "app-store",
>             "buildFlag": [
>                 "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
>                 "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
>                 "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
>             ]
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

I'm not sure if this answers all your questions, but at least it should clear a few.

Comment: Thank you for answering, although I figured it out a while back. Xcode was broken at the time after a failed updated so I was doing everything through the command line. Didn't know it would have solved my problems back then.